# How can I use a Quarto Extension that I created for myself?

Tags: rstudio, quarto

I just created a Quarto extension for myself, and now I was trying to see if I can use it in my other  project. When I tried to install it from github, it gave me error:

```
ERROR: TypeError: Invalid URL
```

And then I downloaded the zip file from the github, and tried to install it from the local zip file. Then the error changed to

```
ERROR: Invalid extension
```

My Quarto version is

```
quarto::quarto_version()
[1] ‘1.0.37’
```

And the Rstudio version is

```
RStudio 2022.11.0-daily+115 "Elsbeth Geranium" Daily (6e803f1628196c4d86f939dd971d7887620f2d19, 2022-08-17) for Windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2022.11.0-daily+115 Chrome/102.0.5005.167 Electron/19.0.10 Safari/537.36
```

What is the issue? I have created the _extension.yml file, the template.qmd file, and added all the resources in the _extensions folder. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

Quarto expects the extension to be versioned and gets confused if it isn't. Try to add a tag to your repo, either via the GitHub release interface, or locally with

```bash
git tag v0.0.1
git push --tags
```

Note that the version should match the one given in `_extension.yml`. Also, using `0.0.0` as the version won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it by making the github repo public. The issue was with the visibility of the extension on github.